# Android and shut down application

Tags: android

I just want to ask a small question. How long my application will be stored in `background` before Android kill it `automatically`. And, will be `onDestroy()` event fired when it happens?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there are any guarantees for how long your app stays in the background, but onDestroy() will be called when your app is killed.

Comment: Its depends when processor need Memory. And if closed then `onDestroy()` will be guarantee called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) onDestroy() is called when "The activity is finishing or being destroyed by the system" That means that you either manually call finish() in your code, or the phone's system needs the resources occupied by your app. When this happens(for example when another app needs those resources) the OS will call onDestroy() on your app.

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy() isn't necessarly called especeally when your app is getting killed.